# Root system problem

Tags: boot, keyboard

I have a root system problem with Ubuntu 14.4

```
errors were found while checking the disk drive for /
```

This is a common problem.
I have followed numerous treads on this site: none have worked!

I therefore went back 3 times to my Ubuntu disk and re-installed the system 3 times. But every times after a few days (not immediately), I fall back to the above line.

After analyzing the problem from multiple angles, I believe that the origin of the problem is that the interface between Ubuntu and my computer is faulty. More specifically, Ubuntu reads "some" computer keys `i` for example as `j`. But not always, most of the time it's OK. (I know this because sometimes, my initial password is rejected 3 times in a row. If I restart the computer, it works fine!)

One more information: My computer is Japanese with a Japanese keyboard and I have the English version of Ubuntu installed. (But this arrangement worked fine with Ubuntu 12.4)

Thank you for your answer.

**PS**: I will download a boot repair disk but I don't think it can solve the issue.

Comment: If it's showing `errors were found while checking the disk drive for /` then it also might be showing that `press F to fix error or S to skip` If it is happening like this then press F.

Comment: I have of course tested the F, S and M (Manual) F works, kind of, since the system loads, but it is completely non-operational. I can see the files but cannot open them, I cannot open any software like Firefox or Ubuntu Software Center. (But system setting works fine!)

Comment: I have now completely reinstalled Ubuntu 14.4 (In Japanese this time but I do not think this is the cause of the problem.) I never had any problem with 12.4, so is 14.4 unstable? Should I install another version?